# Can I get the data from database that makes an API call then pass it to another function that makes an another API call

Tags: reactjs, spfx, react-lifecycle

In react, I want to get data from a database.
I attempted to get the data from database using  getCoor() and put in the constructor method.
I defined variable
private data:any=[];
and defined a state, this.state={data:[]}

Here I am trying to

- Get data from database using API calls
- pass this the data using another API call.

Problem: The data from getCoor is not stored in my variables.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.defaultCoor();
    const Markers = async () => {
      await this.getCoor(); // this.data=json;
      await this.addGoogleMapScript();//do something with this.data 

    }
    Markers();
}
```

The this.data is empty.
I am trying to wait for the getCoor to complete the API call,
get the data and pass to addGoogleMapscript, 
is this possible in React?

Solution

```
private getCoor() {
    const qurl = `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.list}')/items?$select=*&$orderby=Created asc`;

    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    };

    return this.props.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        opt
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json().then((json: any) => {
          this.setState({ data: json.value });
          return (this.data = json); 
        });
      });
  }
```

this.data:any=[]; was defined after the constructors method in the class based React Component
Add **Return** in the API functions and return this.data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the data but not assigning it to a variable. For this to work, your `Markers` function should look something like this.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.defaultCoor();
  const Markers = async () => {
    const data = await this.getCoor();  // this.data=json;
    await this.addGoogleMapScript(data);  //do something with this.data 
  }
  Markers();
}
```

Comment: In my getCoor I have made assignment to the data like this  this.data =json; in my addGoogleMapscript I use this.data for something else but I found this .data is undefined. I am suggesting that this.data will be assigned after the componentDidmount finishes ? If that is the case how can I ensure I get this.data before I run the other functions  using this.data

Comment: Can you post a complete example? This was a little bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks @Mannan it works
 in my  getCoor i forgot to add return return in my API Call